# php script for bootstrap inline checkbox form

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this is really simple

how would I write php script after the submit button is pressed, for a checkbox to stay selected. its not required, but still want it to be able to be selected  here is my code

```
<?php
 ($_POST['submit']) {

 {
 ?>

  <section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
  <form method="post" action="#" role="form">    
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
              <h1>Office Cleaning</h1>

              <?php echo $result;?>

              <p>Please fill out form below</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">           
               <div id="options" style="margin-left:-20.5px">        
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
         <input type="checkbox" value="MDO" name="type"> Medical Office
           </label>
                  </div>
             <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label">
      <input type="checkbox" value="IDO" name="type"> Industrial Office
           </label>
                  </div> 
   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
   <label class="form-check-label">
    <input type="checkbox" value="SO" name="type"> Standard Office
  </label>
  </div>  
  </div> 
 </from>
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple if placed inline in your checkbox input

```
<input type="checkbox" value="MDO" name="type[]" <?php if(isset($_POST['type']) && in_array('MD0', $_POST['type'])){ echo 'checked="checked"; } ?> > Medical Office
```

note the change from `name="type"` to `name="type[]"` as you want to create an array and not just get the last input